# Get perimeter of a binary image

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the perimeter of a binary image by navigating through the black pixels which are connected to at least one white pixel, and surely im not doing this right. It works just fine for the first few pixels but for some reason, it goes out of track of the connected pixels, I mean it can no longer find black pixels. Im probably doing everything wrong but please, please enlighten me.
Thanks in advance,

---

```
public void getPerimeter(){
    int[] start = new int[2];
    start = findStart();
    int[][][] P = new int[8][8][2];
    int[] c = new int[2];
    c[0] = start[0]; c[1] = start[1];
    do{
        P = setNeighbors(c[0], c[1]);
        int i=backTrack(P);
        do{
            if(getPixelval(P[i][i][0], P[i][i][1]) == BLACK){
                ++Perimeter;
                c[0] = P[i][i][0]; 
                c[1] = P[i][i][1];
                prev[0] = P[i-1][i-1][0];
                prev[1] = P[i-1][i-1][1];
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }while(true);
        if(c[0] == start[0] && c[1] == start[1])break;
    }while(true);

}
public int backTrack(int[][][] P){
    int i=0;
    for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
        if(P[j][j][0]==prev[0] && P[j][j][1]==prev[1]){
            return j;
        }

    }
    return i;
}
public int[][][] setNeighbors(int row, int col){

    int[][][] P = new int[8][8][2];

    P[0][0][0] = row-1; P[0][0][1] = col;
    P[1][1][0] = row-1; P[1][1][1] = col-1;
    P[2][2][0] = row;   P[2][2][1] = col-1;
    P[3][3][0] = row+1; P[3][3][1] = col-1;
    P[4][4][0] = row+1; P[4][4][1] = col;
    P[5][5][0] = row+1; P[5][5][1] = col+1;
    P[6][6][0] = row;   P[6][6][1] = col+1;
    P[7][7][0] = row-1; P[7][7][1] = col+1;

    return P;
}
public int[] findStart(){
    int[] spoint = {0,0};
    for(int i=0;i<image.getWidth();i++){
        for(int j=0;j<image.getHeight();j++){
            if(getPixelval(j, i) == BLACK){
                spoint[0] = j;
                spoint[1] = i;
                ++Perimeter;
                prev[0] = j-1;
                prev[1] = i;
                return spoint;
            }
        }
    }
    return spoint;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use quote formatting for things that aren't quotations.

Comment: im sorry.. that's my first post..